# Why doesn't my doorbell have power at the button?

Tags: wiring, doorbell

I tried to install a wired doorbell which has a camera. I did some  online research and learned that it requires a transformer and I checked that a transformer is already there by the breaker panel. I started with installing the chime. I switched off the line to doorbell and installed chime. I switched on the power to doorbell from breaker panel and chime sounded “ding-dong” so I assume that I successfully installed the chime.

I then switched off the main power supply to doorbell again and went outside to install new wired doorbell with camera from SimpliSafe. After its installation, I turned on the power button from the breaker panel but this bell doesn’t ring and the bell switch is not receiving power.

I checked with multimeter that there was no power on the outside wire that goes with the doorbell switch despite the power switch for doorbell was on in breaker panel. However, the chime receives enough power.

Is it normal that the chime bell rings when doorbell switch is turned on from breaker panel?

Do you think that my assumption is right that the outside wire is faulted or has no power coming to it and it requires rewiring?

I might have done a wrong installation as well so please advice.

Thanks
[image][image]

Comment: Did you locate and hook up the other end of the wire to the door at the chime location? Did you check the continuity of that wire with your multimeter, assuming you found it at all? There's generally a reason someone went to wireless doorbells, and if it wasn't to avoid running a wire it all, it's often to avoid fixing a wire that broke and was difficult to repair or replace.

Comment: Wireless doorbell button usually powered from battery.

Comment: The transformer has only one wire that has a set of black and white wires. The doorbell chime wall has two cables coming, both with black and white pair. I connected only one of those I.e. black wire in transformer and white wire in front door screw of the chime box. Then the front doorbell wall has only one cable with black and white cables in it. Am I supposed to screw all cables in chime box? See image.

Comment: Are each of those wire nuts covering a _cable_ (with a white/black wire pair), or is each covering a single wire (a white or a black)? Maybe give us a pic without the nuts on. If they're _cables_ show us where the other end of those cables are terminated. If they're individual wires, should we assume the other end terminates at the box in the other picture?

Comment: Yes, each of those wires have own pair of black and white wires and I used only one pair of it, it’s the one that is marked with a black marker. I didn’t touch black and white pair of second cable. Those cables look like what you see in transformer  picture. The reason I picked only one pair is because it showed voltage when I tested after turning the doorbell switch on from distribution board and shows no voltage after I turned it off from there. The outdoor cable shows no voltage in either case and I assume that single switch in breaker box controls power supply to both ends.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you've connected the two transformer terminals directly to the two chime terminals. That would cause the chime to sound immediately when the power is turned on, and no power would go to the switch.

The correct wiring looks like a loop or ring connecting the transformer, chime, and switch. See [removeandreplace.com](https://removeandreplace.com/2018/10/27/doorbell-does-not-work-how-to-fix-a-doorbell/).

[image]

With your specific cables it could go like this:

1. At transformer, white wire to one terminal and black wire to the other terminal.
2. At chime, white wire from transformer goes to chime's transformer terminal. White wire from button goes to chime's front door terminal. Black wire from transformer connects to black wire from from button. Note: black wires do not connect to chime at all.
3. At button, white wire goes to one terminal of SimpliSafe and black wire goes to the other terminal of SimpliSafe.

Do steps 1 and 2 first, leaving the button wires by the front door disconnected. Turn on power. Touch the bare ends of the button wires to each other. The chime should sound.

After confirming the chime works correctly by touching the wires, turn power off again and do step 3. Then verify the complete system.

Comment: Are you suggesting me that I should be putting one black and white pair of wire coming from transformer into transformer terminal of the chime and another pair of black and white wire into front door terminal? Are both the capped cables behind the wall (see picture) supposed to be connected to the chime? Am I making a mistake by only connecting one pair of black and white wire into chime? I am mimicking exactly as what you see it for transformer in the picture and it is same as the attached diagram.

Comment: @Curioussam Please see the update in my answer.

Comment: Alright, I think that’s the mistake I am making by connecting black and white pair of one cable with the chime and ignoring another cable entirely. I will give it a try later today and update you. I hope this will work now. Thank you so much for your suggestion.

Comment: So I tried the steps you suggested. I attached white part of each cable into the chime I.e. transformer and front parts of the chime. I turned on the main power and bell didn’t ring this time. I went outside and connected the cables but bell didn’t ring. I tried to read voltage on front door cable but it has no reading. I am thinking that the cable is faulty, not sure. Thanks you very much for helping me learn this process.

Comment: @Curioussam You're welcome. You could test the integrity of the cable to the front door as described in the second paragraph of Ecnerwal's answer.

Comment: Yes, I will follow those instructions as well. I need to purchase a multimeter for that. Thanks guys you all are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your wiring scheme at the chime is less than clear from your wording in the comments, and your pictures don't show it. Sounds like you have not connected the black from the door or the white from the transformer to anything - or if you have, you didn't say to what.

Honestly to start with, since you do HAVE a multimeter, you should check the front door wire - first with both ends disconnected to make sure that there isn't a short (should have no continuity / infinite ohms between the wires) and then with the wires at the end you are not testing from twisted together (should have continuity / low ohms.)

That verifies that the **wire is intact**, and works properly, and the two ends you have are **actually** the two ends of the same wire...

Wiring at the chime location would depend on the wiring diagram of the system you are using. Most have connections on the chime (or in its box) for all the wires - i.e. two for the transformer, two for the front door, two for the back door if any, and needed connections between them are "built into the box."

For some "less advanced in the art of design" products you would need to connect one wire from the transformer to one wire of the doorbell directly, and the other wire from each would connect to the chime.

Comment: You are right, I have not made it clear in my previous comment, I apologize. The wall cables that you are seeing are for chime and I had put the cap back in order to put wireless chime back on the wall. If you see those caps closely then you will notice that one of those is marked with a black marker and I attached only that cable to the chime, same as you see in transformer. Talking about multimeter, I have a very basic one and when I tried it on front door wires, it didn't show any reading for voltage. However the cables for chime has reading of 12V-120V~ AC

Comment: I also found that it's AC/DC Voltage tester and doesn't test continuity. I apologize for misinformation again.

Comment: Is this an old style chime that uses selonoids that when connected smash into a piece of metal that dings or is it some sort of electronic chime?  I suspect it has to be an old school chime because the door camera uses power flowing through the selonoid coils to power the camera.

Comment: I have no idea about that.